# Setting a proper ordering of a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have two lists like:

```
>> K = 3
>> ll_G = ['GIO_%s' % (k) for k in range(K)]
>> ll_P = ['PAX_%s' % (k) for k in range(K)]
>> ll_GP = ll_G + ll_P
>> ll_GP
['GIO_0', 'GIO_1', 'GIO_2', 'PAX_0', 'PAX_1', 'PAX_2']
```

I want to order the final list such to have:

```
['GIO_0', 'PAX_0', 'GIO_1', 'PAX_1', 'GIO_2',  'PAX_2']
```

I guess it could be quite simple: how can I do?

Comment: First step: Specify what you want. Unless that exact list there is always it. But then you have it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two lists like

Why not just build the desired list directly?

```
>>> K = 3
>>> [s % k for k in range(K) for s in ('GIO_%s', 'PAX_%s')]
['GIO_0', 'PAX_0', 'GIO_1', 'PAX_1', 'GIO_2', 'PAX_2']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
ll_GP.sort(key = lambda x: x[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to loop on two base lists and add elements to final list in alternating fashion i.e something like this

```
for i in range(len(11_G)):
    11_GP.append(11_G[i])
    11_GP.append(11_P[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by last symbol:

```
sorted(abc, key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+$', x)[0]))
```

The `int(re.findall(r'\d+$', x)[0])` takes the numbers on the end and use their integer representation as a key for comparison.